# Combining accelerometer and GPS to calculate vehicle velocity

Tags: gps, accelerometer

I'm working on a system that requires an updated input from vehicle speed with a frequency of 15hz. The gps provides speed updates with a frequency of 1hz. Im thinking of using the accelerometer to estimate the speed between the speed "updates" from the gps. My question here  if this is a "good" way of doing this or is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a good way. Google Tech Talk (search for Sensor Fusion) exlained way this cannot work well.

Just take the speed value from the GPS chip and write the App in a way that you can ignore speeds under walking speed.